# graph search facebook api (get feeds by user id)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to get posts from me/home for some list of users?

```
me/home?q= userIds = someUserIds
```

I need to sort post by users in my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `profileId/feed` so if you have a list of users, just substitute their profileID's in. For example:

[cocacola/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=cocacola%2Ffeed)

[barackobama/feed](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=barackobama%2Ffeed)